# Why is PHP's trim() not removing trailing blank space?

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

The following line is not echoing the expected result:

```
echo "|".trim(" Laura Suárez Samper ")."|";
```

The above outpus:

```
|Laura Suárez Samper |
```

If I urlencode() the blank space I get:

```
%e2%80%83
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Then it's Unicode whitespace, EM SPACE.

Comment: was just going to say that ^ [`&#8195`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2003/index.htm) - However, my result was indeed `|Laura Suárez Samper|` strangely enough.

Comment: So I just found this multibyte-safe trim: `function mb_trim($str) { return preg_replace("/(^\s+)|(\s+$)/us", "", $str); }`  Can anyone tell me the meaning of `us` ?

Comment: Here's what they mean http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: Well that function did not work. I'm manually editing that field in the DB to remove that space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went ahead and used the following unicode-safe trim:

```
function unicodeSafeTrim($str)
{
    // unicode-safe trim, removes other and sepatator categories.
    return preg_replace("/^[\pZ\pC]+|[\pZ\pC]+$/u", "", $str);
}
```

It worked like a charm.